# How to output host-specific variable along with hostname for all tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Instead of the usual output which shows only status and hostname, how can I also output the value of a host-specific variable that is loaded from inventory.py under the `_meta["hostvars"]` key?

Looking for output something like:

```
TASK [Ping host]
********************************************
ok: [192.168.80.1] foo   
ok: [192.168.80.2] bar   
ok: [192.168.80.3] foo2
```

I want this to happen independent of OK/FAILURE/UNREACHABLE task status.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list). You'll have to [write one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html).